# AS3 - Not Retrieving Correct Item

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

In this section of code, I'm checking if a level in a game is unlocked or not. The Array "levels" contains 12 Movieclips and "levelsUnlocked" is the users highest level reached. So with this code, I'm checking if the level position is higher than the levelsUnlocked value, and if it is, it moves it to frame 2(which is the locked image), if is lower, it keeps it at frame 1.

My question is:

In the else statement, when I refer to levels[levels.length - i], it doesn't treat it as a Movieclip, but if I were to refer to it as levels[1] or levels[3], it does. Can someone tell my why this is happening?

```
function unlockLevels():void
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < levels.length; i++)
            {
                if (levels.length - i > levelsUnlocked)
                {
                    levels[levels.length - i].gotoAndStop(2);
                }
                else
                {
                    levels[levels.length - i].gotoAndStop(1);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array length gives you the length of the array like this :

```
var a:Array = [0,1,2,3,4]
var length:int = a.length
trace(a)
//=> 5
```

in your first iteration in the loop your int is zero.

```
a[a.length - 0]
// a[5] == undefinded
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MovieClip(levels[levels.length-i]).gotoAndStop(2);`

Edit:
Answer for your question:
You're trying to access the array elements from the end of the array while looping.
someArray[someArray.length-i] gives the "last - i" element of the array.

Comment: I tried that and received "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference."

Comment: Why do you go backwards? Why don't you just: levels[i].gotoAndStop(2);

Comment: Just a bandaid, didn't answer the question, "Can someone tell my why this is happening?"